# Python frozen app filetype

Tags: python, file

I've got a python GUI application (wx) that is able to open zip files with an alternate extension (.giz).

```
def GetGIZData(self, filepath):
    #{extract the zip to a temp dir and read the files}
    pass
```

My question is this: if I've got a file at C:\InputFile.giz, how do I get a handle on "C:\InputFile.giz" from a frozen python app in Windows when I double click on InputFile.giz? (Essentially I'm looking to replicate the functionality you get where double clicking a word document opens Word and displays the file, except for my own application and my own file type.)

I've read documentation about [how to register a file type with an application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127451%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but I can't seem to find anything about how to get at the file path of the file that was clicked inside a python app.

Any ideas?

Comment: giz? People might get the wrong idea, you know.

Comment: Is the problem that you don't know about [`sys.argv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv), or that it's not showing up in `sys.argv` because `wx` is doing something fancy to accept files even after launch and you don't know what that fanciness is?

Comment: @MarceloCantos: It's a hard "g". ;-)

Comment: @abarnert: Yup, the problem was that I don't know about sys.argv. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app isn't registered to accept files after launch, double-clicking a `.giz` file will run a new copy of your program, with the file's path as the first argument. This means it will be available as [`sys.argv[1]`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv) to your script.

`wx` also makes the same list of arguments available as the `argv` attribute on the `wx.App` object, but IIRC that's not actually documented in the [Python version of the class](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.App-class.html) because it's unnecessary.